# Ifelse utilizando "/" - R

Tags: r, if

Tenho uma coluna com as datas no seguinte formato: "01/05/2022" (formatado como character). Preciso gerar uma nova coluna com a abreviação de cada mês, no caso citado o resultado seria "mai". Não tenho interesse em transformar a coluna como data, o intuito é realmente deixar nesse formato de character. Estou tentando fazer essa alteração com o uso de `if`, no entanto não estou conseguindo:

```
dt_criacao <- "01/05/2022"

mes_criacao <- ifelse(dt_criacao == "/05/", "mai", "outros")
```

O intuito é pegar apenas o mês e retornar a abreviação dele, por isso o uso das duas "/". Com esse teste ele retornou apenas "outros".

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Edite a pergunta inserindo o resultado de `dput(head(base_atual, 2))`

Comment: Olá Murilo, bem vindo ao SOpt. Editei sua pergunta para torná-la reproduzível, veja se concorda com a edição. Se preferir,inclua uma amostra dos seus dados, como indicado no comentário acima. Se está começando no site, recomendo ler o [Manual de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) criado pela comunidade.

Answer (score 1):

Não está funcionando porque não tem nenhum valor que corresponda à condição ("/01/" não é o mesmo que "12/01/2022", por exemplo). Pode usar `grepl`, que identifica padrão:

```
ifelse(grepl("/05/", dt_criacao), "mai", "outros")
#> [1] "mai"
```

Mas se vai fazer isso para 12 meses, é mais simples converter para `Date` e depois formatar para exibir apenas o mês abreviado. A saída da `format` é em `character`.

```
data <- c("01/05/2021", "01/01/2022")

mes <- format(as.Date(data, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%b")

mes
#> [1] "mai" "jan"

class(mes)
#> [1] "character"
```